# How to check for characters other than the first character in a regular expression

Tags: java, regex, expression, special-characters

I have a regular expression to check for certain characters (including the necessary escape characters) in a Java module:

```
[:;|=,+\\[\\]\\*?<>@\\+\"/]
```

I'm using `java.util.regex.Matcher.find` to locate the regex characters and this works fine.
I also need to check for the backslash `\`, but ignore the first instance of it.

I can do this separately using the commons lang `countMatches` method. I was just wondering if there's a way to do this only using regex?

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I do not understand what you refer to by "this" in "I can do this separately". The entire point of your question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this fits your requirements, not matching the first `\` then matching other all escaped characters

```
(?!^[\\])[:;|=,+\[\]\*?<>@\\+\"/]
```

[Example Execution](http://regexr.com?3853o)